# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cookiecutter'

Tags: cookiecutter

Just upgraded my Mac to  macOS Monterey 12.6, I am trying to use the python to create a project from a cookiecutter, throws this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cookiecutter'
```

Answer (score 0):

The question has been solved

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

python3 -m pip install --user cookiecutter
```